# Load a JavaScript-Module with @ResourceDependency

Tags: jsf

**Status Quo**

- My Application uses a custom `@FacesComponent`.
- This Component needs some JavaScript-Resources, which are added with `@ResourceDependency`.

**Change**
With the latest Release of the JavaScript-Code used, the script has become an ES6 Module.

**Problem**

- JSF loads the Resource with `<script type="text/javascript" src=[...]></script>`
- How do I adopt my JSF-Code to achieve `type="module"`?
  (complete example: `<script type="module" src=[...]></script>`)

**What I've tried so far**
Setting the ContentType of the Resource to "module" in a custom `ResourceHandlerWrapper` does not work, but should(?) according to [the Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/javax.faces.Outputjavax.faces.resource.Script.html)...

```
public class MyResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {
    
    public MyResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        var res = super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
        if (resourceName.equals("module.js") && libraryName.equals("test")) {
            res.setContentType("module");
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. It should. Which JSF impl/version exactly are you using?

Comment: I am using openliberty 23.0.0.4 with webprofile-9.1.